# ORA-00904 Invalid identifier and column ambiguity

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run the following sql query:

```
select customers.cust_first_name, customers.cust_last_name, customers.cust_gender,
customers.cust_city, countries.country_name, products.prod_id
from customers
join countries on customers.cust_id = countries.country_id
join products on profits.prod_id = products.prod_id
join profits on customers.cust_id = profits.cust_id
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-00904: "PROFITS"."PROD_ID":Invalid identifier 
00904.00000-"%s: invalid Identifier"
```

I am using oracle 11g version.

Could you also guide me on how to dynamically solving/dealing with column ambiguity problem, i.e. if there is a way of getting the database to ignore column ambiguity issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name the table in the `from` clause before you can use it in an `on` statement:

```
select customers.cust_first_name, customers.cust_last_name, customers.cust_gender,
       customers.cust_city, countries.country_name, products.prod_id
from customers join
     countries
     on customers.cust_id = countries.country_id join
     profits
     on customers.cust_id = profits.cust_id join
     products
     on profits.prod_id = products.prod_id;
```

Your query would also be more readable if you used table aliases:

```
select cu.cust_first_name, cu.cust_last_name, cu.cust_gender,
       cu.cust_city, co.country_name, pr.prod_id
from customers cu join
     countries co
     on cu.cust_id = co.country_id join
     profits pf
     on cu.cust_id = pf.cust_id join
     products pr
     on pf.prod_id = pr.prod_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with answer. Could you also clear my doubt that there is no way database will ignore column ambiguity problem, unless explicitly mentioned in the query. In other words can we avoid adding prefixes to duplicates columns in our query?

Comment: @kashif4u . . . I think adding table prefixes to columns is a good idea.  You don't need them if the column name is unique -- as it seems to be in your tables for most columns because the column name starts with a table prefix.  If you use a `natural join` or `using` clause, then you can refer to the join columns without a prefix according to the standard (I'm not sure if Oracle supports this though).

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have another query for you. Further to you suggestions I tried looking into online literature but could'nt find docs on multiple joins.

Comment: This query is giving me the same trouble. Thanks                        select PROFITS.QUANTITY_SOLD, PROFITS.UNIT_COST, PRODUCTS.PROD_NAME, PRODUCTS.PROD_DESC, COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME, COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_REGION from COUNTRIES join CUSTOMERS on COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID = CUSTOMERS.COUNTRY_ID join PROFITS on PRODUCTS.CUST_ID = PROFITS.CUST_ID join CUSTOMERS on PROFITS.CUST_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID.

Comment: @kashif4u . . . And it has the same problem.  Read my answer and understand the difference between the query that works and the one that doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have finally figured out finally how to put together complex joins, it took litter brain storming but it was worth it. Cheers